# Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3 adding android platform Error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

When i add platform i am getting this error how to resolve :

```
C:\Users\SCube\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                        throw e;
                              ^
    Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
    ed to your path.
        at C:\Users\SCube\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:4
    7:27
        at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\SCube\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\co
    rdova\src\superspawn.js:112:23)
        at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
        at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Thanks

Comment: You are using windows or Mac machine.

Comment: hi Imran i am using window machine

Comment: hi imran i check but please let me know javaHome and antHome how to set

Comment: hi imran if u can  give support on team viewer so that better

Comment: heh i m in office buddy. do u know that... check here for Java and ant home set up - http://www.dominikgorecki.com/2012/12/installing-cordovaphonegap-for-android-on-windows-a-suppliment/

Comment: ok imran thanks i will try and let u know

Comment: hi imran C:\>set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\antsss;

C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0;

C:\>set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:\>ant -version
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
what shall i do know i have install cordova

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs, when your path is not set proper for Android Application.Please follow this [BLOG](http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html) for adding Android Platform in Windows Machine

**Can try this also to Setup your PATH environment variable on Windows**

- List item From the Desktop, right-click My Computer and click Properties.
- Click Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
- In the System Properties window click the Environment Variables button.
- Select the PATH variable from the System variables section.
- Select the Edit button.
  You need to add the path to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. In my example I will use **"C:\Development\android-sdk-windows"** as the directory the SDK is installed in. Append the following text into the text box:
  ;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Development\android-sdk-windows\tools
- Save your edit. Close the Environment Variables dialog.
- Additionally, you may need to include %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type java. If the program can not be found add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %JAVA_HOME% environment variable.
- Finally, you may need to include %ANT_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type ant. If the program can not be found add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %ANT_HOME% environment variable.

  For More details You can refer [HERE](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android)

Comment: imran i did this C:\>set ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files\antsss;

C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0;

C:\>set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

C:\>ant -version
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
 and i am getting error

Comment: user3151224 try this and follow steps carefully http://www.andrewsavory.com/blog/2013/2517